# Why might weird characters ($p) appear at beginning of every file in vim?

Tags: vim

Every file I open in vim lately, even new empty files, as a ($p) at the beginning. This does not appear to be *real* - inserting text overwrites it, and once it's overwritten it does not return.

I have no idea what might be doing this, or how to fix it.

Comment: What's in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Do you get this with `vim -U NONE` (which skips your `.vimrc` initialization file)?  If the answer is no, see if you can revert to an older copy of your `.vimrc` or else try removing lines until you find the culprit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better to ask it at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdamKatz A good guess, but it shows up even then.

Answer (score 9):

Fixed: I resolved this issue on OSX 10.13.4 by updating to iTerm2 3.1.5

vim github issue #2008 reveals it's your terminal emulator not supporting certain DCS (Device Control Strings)

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2008

Works for me with version combination:

VIM version 8.0.1283

iTerm2 3.1.15

OSX 10.13.4